# Prove that $|\mathbb{R} - \{r\}| = c$ for every real number $r$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking to prove the statement in the title, namely $|\mathbb{R} - \{r\}| = c$ for every real number $r$. Obviously $|\mathbb{R}| = c$, so I was wondering if I was supposed to find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} - \{r\}$. The function $f : \mathbb{R} - \{r\} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x$ didn't look onto in this case, and I wasn't sure what else to try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f$ such that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x=r$}\\
n+1 & \text{ if $x=n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$}\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: And how $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran $f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Take $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R} - \{r\}$ then $$c =|[a,b]| \leq |\mathbb{R}  - \{r\}| \leq | \mathbb{R}| = c$$

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps.

1. Show that $\Bbb R-\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R$ have a bijection between them (this can be taken as a function extending a very simple bijection between some $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $A-\{0\}$).
2. Show that for any $r\in\Bbb R$ there is a bijection between $\Bbb R-\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R-\{r\}$.

Comment: I'd be happy to improve this, if there's really something wrong with this answer (and not, say, with the answerer).